# Qr Scan Flutter can't scan properly

Tags: android, ios, flutter

`qr_flutter: ^4.1.0`

[QR Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_flutter)

This qr flutter package scan any static view..
Like white paint, table or even carpet and return 7 to 8 digits random string like this. (12709321)

How to deal with it?.
or any other package...

Comment: other package > try [mobile_scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/mobile_scanner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was use this package put show some issue in it
now i use this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/ai_barcode_scanner)

its simple and support by google ML